# C# Entityframework - Como limpar FK field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Preciso de ajuda com uma operação de update de uma entidade pelo EntityFramework

Eu quero limpar um relacionamento entre duas entidades.
Imagine um cenário de exemplo abaixo, eu tenho uma entidade de "Agente" para uso geral, e uma entidade de configurações para agentes relacionados a salário:

```
    public class Agente
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigSalario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Agente AgenteSalario { get; set; }
        public Agente AgenteAdiantamento { get; set; }
        public Agente AgenteFerias { get; set; }
        public Agente Agente13 { get; set; }
    }
```

Quando eu executo um update na entidade ConfigSalario, alterando algum dos agentes indicando o id do novo agente, o update funciona corretamente e a alteração é feita em banco, através do código abaixo:

```
configSalario.AgenteSalario = contexto.Agentes.Find(novoAgenteId);
contexto.ConfigSalario.Update(configSalario);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

O problema ocorre quando eu mando um dos agentes como nulo, com o objetivo de apagar o agente especifico dentro da tabela de configurações.

```
configSalario.AgenteSalario = null;
contexto.ConfigSalario.Update(configSalario);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

O resultado....não ocorre nada, o entityframework não apaga o valor na situação acima.
Como faço para apagar o valor de uma campo de uma tabela no EF, principalmente se este campo for uma FK de uma tabela, e meu único objetivo é desfazer o vínculo????

EDIT. Na tabela de configurações de salário no banco permite nulo nos campos de agentes. Uso SqlServer.

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo você permitindo null na propriedade Fk na tabela, você tem que informa o ef core.

```
public Guid? AgenteSalarioId {get: set:}
```

Dessa forma o ef core entendera que é possível receber null na propriedade `AgenteSalario`

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte.